# BSOD on a new build

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, windows-10, ssd, bsod

I just finished my first build with the following config a couple of days ago:

Adata SSD 120
Corsair 16 GB (8X2) 2400 MHZ 
Asus Maximus viii hero
intel i7-6700k

I have tried several times to install windows, ranging from 7 to 10 each time I install it and then put my motherboard cd in, install drivers the system will crash randomly giving me a BSOD. I tried running Ubuntu earlier which worked flawless. I love ubuntu and I use it at my day job, however I am trying to learn Unity so I am a bit bound to use Windows. I have downloaded all the tried iso files from official microsoft offered downloads - 90 day trials.

The only message I get is "Critical process died" I have been searching everywhere but nothing concrete seems to point me to the right direction.

Please help! In order to give more details about the erroe, I am unsure which files to copy as stack trace here and where I can find them

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Okay, let me check that

Comment: Okay, I just ran this, however it tells me there have been no crashes. Eidt, after a new reboot and BSOD in the meantime while I was typing this comment

Comment: Usually because It can't data from hard drive Or memory. Boot to safe mode and run from command prompt;  "sfc.exe /scannow" (without Quotes). Check using a SMART tool As well

Comment: Its gotten into a loop, I think Ill do a fresh install and report back. Just worried what these fresh installs might be causing to my hardware :(.. Cant like windows much with this behavior

Comment: @User3 If it has been crashing after it was turned on completely and you were logged on, I think the only reason it would not log crash dump is either there was paging issue or bios/disk drive drivers are outdated

Comment: I find windows hard :D I suspect it is a SSD issue, as sometimes it returns me to the BIOS page after a BSOD and reboot, I cant see my SSD there, then I manually plug the machine off, replug it and all works ok. However nothing of this sort happens under Ubuntu. I ahve been running eclipse and IntelliJ Idea there.

Comment: Finally I found what was causing this, it was an iterative process and I found that the CD which came with my motherboard was overriding a driver and this was conflicting with Windows, I had to skim through and install drivers one by one. I installed the bare minimum USB, LAN, graphics and SATA drivers. Left all the others